# How can I catch my custom exception with Boost.Test?

Tags: c++, boost

When I'm testing my C++ class with Boost.Test and my custom exceptions are thrown (they are instances of my class), this is the message I see in log:

```
unknown location:0: fatal error in "testMethod": unknown type
```

It's very un-informative and I don't know how to teach Boost.Test to convert my exception to string and display it properly. My `Exception` class has `operator string()`, but it doesn't help. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would work if your custom exception class inherited from [`std::exception`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/exception/).

Comment: Actually I inherited from `std::exception` **and** `std::string` :) Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you need to do both. It should be enough to do former.

Alternatively you can register custom exception translator (for example, if you can't change an exception definition). You can read about the interface in Boost.Test docs.

Comment: Is the inheritance public? It needs to be public inheritance for the output to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if a function throw a specified except by using **BOOST_CHECK_THROW** or similar

see [Boost.Test Docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html):

```
class my_exception{};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test )
{
   int i =  0;
   BOOST_CHECK_THROW( i++, my_exception );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define an operator<< in the std namespace:

```
namespace std {
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Exception& ex) {
        os << ex.string();
        return os;
    }
}
```

This should allow boost.test to display the contents of your exception.

I've found this necessary so that objects can be tested with BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(), etc.

Comment: I don't think this works. I tried: https://gist.github.com/davidmatson/3ee2fd34e5941cda76f12cba411430d8

Answer (score 0):

I just inherited it from `std::string` and everything works fine.

Comment: If it is a custom exception, why don't you inherit from std::exception and implement what() instead of inheriting from std::string and implementing string()? Then you will be able to do a catch(const std::exception& ex) { std::cerr << ex.what(); }